# error coming up only in mozila

Tags: css, html, w3c-validation

My website is in w3validation.
I have done some minor changes in website. after done some changes I can see below error at specific part.

```
<a _moz-rs-heading="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">SERVICES</a>
```

Above error coming only in mozila rest of browser is fine. due to this error I can face some margin related issues. I don't know how do generate error?

Anyone suggest me how can I resolve this error.

Thanks in advance
Rakesh

Comment: After reading @vishwanath's reply I realise how confusing your question is. Am I right in thinking the question is: "In firefox a new attribute is automatically being added to my anchor tag. How can I stop this happening?".

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, but automatic html generation for firefox.

This may help to resolve the problem.

http://drupal.org/node/140241

Comment: Yes, _moz-rs-heading is inserted for some incorrect HTML. See also http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1221

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the error in the validator is being raised because `_moz-rs-heading` isn't a valid html attribute.

In HTML5 you can prefix attributes with `data-` if you need to include some extra data in your tags such as `data-moz-rs-heading`.

```
<a data-moz-rs-heading="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">SERVICES</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion, there is definetly a bug in the firefox besteffort implementation since version 3.6.
I encountered this issue on a user contributed html code in a separate div block : the user used a <b> tag, forgetting to close it.
Since Firefox 3.6, the unclosed <b> is then dynamically completed by firefox with a closing </b> tag before the closing </div> tag. This is allright. But it is also immediatley reopened by Firefox after the closing </div> tag, and so on.
Thus, quite a simple error done in an user contributed block does now propagated to the whole html code following it. This is quite a nasty new "best-effort". I know "best-effort can not fix all cases, in particuliar if the user start to close or open block tag randomly.
But propagating errors in handling inlines tags outside of their containing block tag, it is weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you use short named anchors `<a id="loc001"/>` in XHTML it too can happen.

Firefox and Chrome rendered it incorrectly. I had to change them to `<a id="loc001"></a>`